# Не могу подключиться к localhost

Tags: linux, сеть, localhost, telnet

Не могу подключиться к 127.0.0.1, на любой порт фаерфокс пишет "connection blocked". Не знаю, в чем вообще причина, вот что говорят некоторые команды.

ifconfig:

```
enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 68:b5:99:f0:5a:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd0700000-d0720000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 384  bytes 31396 (30.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 384  bytes 31396 (30.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7705:a362:6896:aa73  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd01::8b8e:b898:43cf:5abd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:23:14:17:f3:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30236  bytes 21577035 (20.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27621  bytes 5027406 (4.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

telenet:

```
$ telnet -4 localhost
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
$ telnet -6 localhost
  Trying ::1...
  telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
```

netstat:

```
$ netstat -anp|grep 127.0.0.1
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

`curl 127.0.0.1:8000`, что интересно, грузит HTML-код с сервера, правда, без CSS и JavaScript. В браузере во вкадке сначала пишет заголовок сайта, а затем `connection blocked!`. Делаю проект на Django. Подскажите, что можно сделать?
Что еще привести, сходу не знаю, поэтому вот. Fedora 29, если что.

Comment: совершенно непонятна суть вопроса. у вас же всего лишь один tcp-порт — 631-й — слушает какой-то процесс (вероятно, cupsd). больше никто и никаких портов не слушает. // то есть: всё в порядке, именно так и должно всё происходить.

Comment: Не blocked, а refused. И это абсолютно нормально, потому что порт телнета 23 у вас никто не слушает, и принимать ваше подключение тупо некому

Comment: Что у вас с браузером и портом 8000, непонятно, недостаточно данных. По вашему netstat получается, что curl не должен работать по причине отсутствия порта 8000, но если он у вас работает, то значит вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966456/178576

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос Ваш говорит о том, что вы очень туманно представляете работу сети.

Ну подумайте, вот Вы пишите в командной строке команду:

```
telnet -4 localhost
```

Это означает, что вы желаете, что бы программа *telnet* установила соединение через порт 23  на localhost с некоей программой, которая работает на localhos и слушает порт 23.

*netstat* Вам показывает некую инфу, которая Вам совершенно не нужна :-) Сделайте проще:

```
netstat -ltu | grep LISTEN
```

Скорее всего, порт 23 не слушает **никто**! Поэтому попытка соединения и отвергается *localhost* :

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

А что можно ожидать другого?! Запустите на *localhost* демон, слушающий 23 порт (например - *telnetd*) и ситуация изменится на обратную.

Точно так же и с HTTP соединением. Протокол HTTP использует порт 80. Но на *localhost* этот порт никто не слушает. Поэтому, попытка написать в адресной строке браузера *http://localhost* ничем хорошим не кончится. В соединении будет точно так же отказано.

Запустите на *localhost* любой HTTP сервер (пусть - самфй простой, типа *boa*  или *lightdm* и этот сервер подхватит Ваш запрос на соединение.

Comment: - А кто у  вас слушает 23-й порт? - 23-й порт у нас слушает никто!

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk * А кто у вас слушает 23-й порт?* - у нас - это где? На моём рабочем  компе - никто  не слушает, т.к. это мне не нужно. А на хостах, для которых я делаю ПО, там слушает *telnetd*. Он мне нужен для отладки моих программ, вот я его там и запускаю при загрузке хоста.

Comment: Это было адресовано не вам. Просто вспомнил интервью Эскобара.

Answer (score 0):

проверьте настройки фаервола: (# systemctl status firewalld), если запущен и есть GUI настраивайте.
Или iptables (#iptables -L -n -v)