# connection blocked при подключении к localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, django, сеть, firewall

На днях задавал уже этот вопрос, но сразу ответы не прочитал и не уточнил ничего, что как, так что перезадам.

Проблема следующая: делаю приложение на Django (python), при запуске сервера он прослушивает  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ порт, и раньше всё было нормально, но в какой-то момент вместо сайта начало выдавать "connection blocked". Так получилось, что из-за этого я переустановил систему, но в системе из коробке выдаёт точно ту же ошибку. Кстати, да, как там заметили, я "очень туманно представляю работу сети", это так.

Вот что выдает `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`:

```
tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:3306      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     -
tcp       0      0 127.0.0.53:53       0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     -
tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     -
tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:631       0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     -
tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:8000      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     29424/python3.7
tcp6      0      0 :::22               :::*           LISTEN     -
tcp6      0      0 ::1:631             :::*           LISTEN     -
```

Насколько я понимаю, он говорит, что django прослушивает 127.0.0.1:8000, но подключиться я к нему не могу.
 `ss -ltupn | grep LISTEN` тоже говорит это же:

```
tcp    LISTEN   0      80         127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*
tcp    LISTEN   0      128    127.0.0.53%lo:53      0.0.0.0:*
tcp    LISTEN   0      128          0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:*
tcp    LISTEN   0      5          127.0.0.1:631     0.0.0.0:*
tcp    LISTEN   0      10         127.0.0.1:8000    0.0.0.0:*   users:(("python3.7",pid=29424,fd=4))
tcp    LISTEN   0      128             [::]:22         [::]:*
tcp    LISTEN   0      5              [::1]:631        [::]:*
```

Да, ещё мне показалось странным, и в том вопросе я это упоминал, `curl 127.0.0.1:8000 > ./Desktop/file.html` нормально грузит сайт. Ну, вдруг это что-то значит, я хз.

Помогите, из-за чего такое может происходить и как исправить? ("измените настройки фаервола" - я не знаю, как это делать :) )

elementary 5 (Ubuntu 18)

upd: попробовал еще несколько раз перезапустить, обнаружил, что если открывать сайт по ссылке, когда браузер закрыт, то страница загружается, однако после этого всё сразу блочится. А ещё только что сервер выдал такую ошибку:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 45692)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Вдруг что-то скажет.

Comment: после перезапуска ваш сервер обрабатывает **один** запрос, после чего остальные запросы блокирует. разбирайтесь с самим сервером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хаха, всё было настолько глупо, насколько это возможно. У меня в фаерфоксе стоит аддон на впн, я его включал, чтобы полазить на лурке, а потом забыл выключить. И мой запрос в браузере обрабатывался не моим локальным сервером, а впн-сервером, и он блочил эти запросы. А курл работал, так как он подключался сразу к компьютеру.

А ещё оказалось, что там даже есть специальная настройка, которая не дает такому случитьс. Ну что ж, зато теперь у меня есть опыт, что проверять в подобной ситуации.